# r White Hat webscrape whitelisting

Tags: r, web-scraping, bots, whitelist

I've been periodically doing web scrapes for an eCommerce client of mine and getting through with read_html with no issues up until recently. It seems they've now upgraded their website security and my current attempts are now being blocked.

As this is an expected function, I should be able to get them to add me to their whitelist (and maybe use a more efficient scraping technique)

As I've never asked IT to whitelist a crawler before, would I just need them to whitelist my IP address? Is there some sort of bot profile that I need to create? Any help will be appreciated. For now, I just need to be able to scrape the raw html code

Comment: Short answer: I don't know. Long answer (from those who deal with companies that specifically allow access like this): only they know how they are filtering/restricting, and therefore how best to permit you the access you think you need. "Blocked" could be a number of things, including (1) oauth2 auth, in which case you need to get your credentials and refresh credentials keys and use them; (2) rate-limiting, perhaps your allow-list concept is sufficient; (3) either/both of those could be mitigated by API keys (if they support it).

Answer (score 0):

I got things sorted. They needed a combination of my user agent string, and my IP address. so I sent them xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, "ExampleBot; +https://example.net"

Something like this worked for the read_html command:

html <- try(read_html(GET(webpage, user_agent("ExampleBotBot; +https://example.net"))))
#Not my real bot's user agent

that code reads the html text of the page into the html variable so I can parse it with rvest